# metadata API: howto deploy only what specified in package.xml

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, metadata, salesforcedx-cli

I'm using [mdapi:deploy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm#cli_reference_deploy).  How do I tell it to deploy ONLY the metadata is defined in my package.xml instead of all the metadata files on my local filesystem?

Ex package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>MyObj__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>43.0</version>
</Package>
```

When I run `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -u <me> -d ./metadata` it tries to deploy `metadata/objects/*` and I get errors saying `<object> not defined in package.xml`

Why do I need to even have a `package.xml` if it is going to deploy everything specified in `-d` anyways...

**UPDATE:** I've made a tool to solve this problem.  [mdapi-smart-deploy](https://github.com/rynop/mdapi-smart-deploy).  Would appreciate feedback.  Note it is intended for non-production deploys (ex: sandbox).

**UPDATE 2:** I've abandoned my tool for now, in favor of [Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/) for IntelliJ.  While I'm not a fan of IntelliJ, it solves all the problems discussed here (and more).  I highly recommend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Metadata API expects a self-consistent package file set, meaning the `package.xml` and the metadata source are exactly aligned with one another. Salesforce DX's Metadata API commands aren't doing any special magic; it's zipping up that MDAPI source and package file and deploying it just like Ant or Workbench would. MDAPI is much older than Salesforce DX and in many ways a bit weird by the standards of modern deployment tools.

SFDX, when the `force:source:convert` command is issued, builds such a consistent MDAPI file set from the current DX project. If you want to deploy only a portion of your overall project, you can edit the `package.xml` and file tree to match, or break up your DX project into logically separate artifacts and convert them individually to MDAPI-deployable packages.

Comment: Something I had discovered during one of the CI implementations. Had posted an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CNhWQAW) to see if this behavior can be customized so that *package.xml* picks only what's defined in it instead of scanning the source folder. This would have been very helpful in case of delta deployments.

Comment: Thanks David.  I still don't understand the need for a package.xml if the metadata files are the source of truth.

Comment: @JayantDas I'm writing an OSS tool to fill the gap I'm looking for in this question.  I'll post it back here when I'm done.

Comment: @rynop That sounds super useful. I'd like to see it too!

Comment: @rynop That will be indeed helpful.

Comment: DavidReed & @JayantDas I've released an initial version of my tool at https://github.com/rynop/mdapi-smart-deploy comments/PRs welcome.

Comment: @rynop Thanks for sharing. Did you also take a look at what Martin provided in his answer with the `autoUpdatePackage` option? I am quite sure it was not available when I was stuck with this situation (unless I badly missed it). Something that may be helpful here.

Comment: @JayantDas yup I did. I don't see `autoUpdatePackage` exposed anywhere in the SFDC CLI tool for me to leverage.  So I was still stranded with needing to create the zip manually (or write a tool that did it).  For me, there is still benefit for tracking a single `package.xml` in your git repo (teams of devs merge back additions/subtractions from their feature branch).  My tool solves both.  Lets dev's focus on the code, and tool handles deploy & package.xml bloat/mess.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has to do with the tool you are using, rather than with the metadata api itself.

It is entirely possible to have a package that contains a definition of a custom object that is ignored on deployment if it isn't included in the `package.xml` file.

I believe the relevant setting in the deploy call is `autoUpdatePackage`. From the [metadata api documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm):

> If a file is in the .zip file but not specified in package.xml,
>   specifies whether the file is automatically added to the package. A
>   retrieve() is issued with the updated package.xml that includes the
>   .zip file.
>
> Do not set this argument for deployment to production orgs.

---

A simple deployment package with two new objects defined:

```
[martin@localhost Test-CreateObject]$ unzip -l package.zip 
Archive:  package.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  07-31-2018 09:49   objects/
      426  07-31-2018 09:49   objects/CreateMe_1__c.object
      426  07-31-2018 09:49   objects/CreateMe_2__c.object
      236  07-31-2018 09:40   package.xml
---------                     -------
     1088                     4 files
```

The contents of the files, showing the package manifest only lists one object:

```
[martin@localhost Test-CreateObject]$ cat package.xml objects/*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>CreateMe_1__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>37.0</version>
</Package>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <deploymentStatus>Deployed</deploymentStatus>
    <nameField>
        <label>CreateMe 1</label>
        <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <type>Text</type>
    </nameField>
    <label>CreateMe 1</label>
    <sharingModel>Private</sharingModel>
</CustomObject>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <deploymentStatus>Deployed</deploymentStatus>
    <nameField>
        <label>CreateMe 2</label>
        <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <type>Text</type>
    </nameField>
    <label>CreateMe 2</label>
    <sharingModel>Private</sharingModel>
</CustomObject>
```

The results of the deployment showing just one object created:

[image]

Comment: Do you know if this deploy option was recently added? I don’t recollect if this was available earlier.

Comment: It's been around for a few years. I don't have a specific api version at the moment though.

Comment: Thanks. That’s interesting because I was in same situation few years back and that I recollect reaching out to support and was responded, that’s how it works by design. I had gone ahead posting an idea for this (link in one of the comments in David’s answer). Interestingly many of us really are not aware of this option.

Comment: Yeah, It's there in the raw api, it just comes down to whether or not your tool supports it. I made my own thing a few years back because I was frustrated with ant. I haven't looked into the sfdx tool enough to know whether or not this option is something you can configure there.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm pretty sure this is what the intellij Illuminated Cloud plugin leverages under the covers.  However I don't want to be tied to an IDE, I want to be able to leverage things i've already setup in the sfdx cli (like orgs, usernames - and their tokens), and I want a CLI to drive it.  I think my tool solves these (I've just started using SFDC so could def have a blind spot here)

Comment: @rynop Sounds good. As long as you've got a setup that works for you.

Comment: Your prob going to laugh, but after writing v1 of my tool, I ended up just using Illuminated Cloud, because dev'ing the last 10% of was going to take too much time.  For others reading this, I would highly recommend Illuminated Cloud.  I appreciate your post because it forced me to think hard about not re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

For those who is still not clear about autoUpdatePackage option, which I admittedly found quite confused before too.

autoUpdatePackage -> autoAddComponentsFromFilesToPackageXml

However, it does not handle auto removal components in your folder but not in package.xml. That means if you want to deploy a subset, you would have to go through your directory and remove the files manually.

Package.xml is almost useless when you set autoUpdatePackage = true & allowMissingFiles = true. The only critical value it brings, in this case, is the api version to deploy against.

Comment: With the `autoUpdatePackage` value set to false, there should be no need to remove files at all. This flag signals to salesforce to ignore those components that are not listed in the package manifest. With the right tool, if you want to deploy a subset of files in a directory, you should just need to update the `package.xml` file to remove the metadata components you don't want to deploy.

Comment: I actually tested this a number of times before and always ran into this error

<object> not defined in package.xml 

even if I set autoUpdatePackage to false.  @martin when was the last time you tried ? would be good to reconcile this so others won't have to guess ;)

Comment: Were you deploying a custom object, or something else, like an Apex class?

Comment: I did custom object, field, validation rules, ... same scenario & error that @rynop mentioned in this thread.

Comment: It should work for custom objects. Although for sub-components that can be deployed explicitly like custom fields, validation rules, workflow rules/alerts/field-updates, and custom labels, they can't be ignored. Profiles and page layouts can be ignored though, probably since their sub-components can't be explicitly included in a package manifest. Static resources can be ignored since they are just singular components, although apex classes can't be ignored.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment that we shouldn't have to guess, but there's still a bit of an art to deploying code to salesforce.

Comment: I also could not get autoUpdatePackage to allow me to deploy only what is in package.xml and ignore anything else in the directory.  I am using Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy and the entire contents of the branch in the repo are deployed.  With autoUpdatePackage set to false, it returns '<object> not defined in package.xml' for all the content of the branch that is not in package.xml.  It seems as if autoUpdatePackage allows deployment to succeed if true, but deploys everything, and gives an error if false.  I'm now looking into this: http://peterknolle.com/using-ant-for-dynamic-deployments/

Answer (score 0):

I reduce the manual task of removing each component from the "src" which were not involved in the package.xml through a Java Program. Yes I know it's not a complete solution for now, but still. Go through the [repo](https://github.com/meta-sankalp-vyas/Selective-Change-Management-of-Project-Repository) and let me know what further enhancements can be done in it.